# Inconsistent Behavior of Mongoose's "select"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working with Node.js, MongoDB, and Mongoose. I noticed a peculiar behavior with the `select` method in Mongoose. There are two situations where the behavior differs:

1. When I save the user object returned by executing the server request and then try to use the `select` method, it doesn't work anymore.
2. However, when I use the `select` method in the same execution as `findById`, it works fine (see the commented code versus the non-commented one).

I encountered a similar issue with the `populate` method, but somehow managed to make it work. I'm unsure about the underlying mechanism and would appreciate some clarification on how this works.

Here's the code snippet I mentioned earlier:

```
export const getCart = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // const userCart = await User.findById(req.user._id).select("cart -_id");

    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
    const userCart = user.select("cart -_id");

    return res.status(200).json(userCart);

  } catch (error) {`enter code here`
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

I want to create a middleware that performs most of this work and passes the user object through the `req` object using `next()`, such as `req.user`. This would allow me to populate it and utilize the methods provided by the Mongoose Schema. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
const userCart = await User.findById(req.user._id).select("cart -_id");
```

is really like...

```
const userCart = await (User.findById(req.user._id).select("cart -_id"));
```

Where the mongo query is built ....

```
{ $where: { _id: req.user._id }, projection: { cart:1, _id: 0} }
```

But this...

```
const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
const userCart = user.select("cart -_id");
```

The mongo query is fired off as

```
{ $where: { _id: req.user._id } }
```

and the `.select` has no effect as it is added too late.

I am assuming something like this would work ok:

```
const userQ = User.findById(req.user._id);
// As long as no async calls between this and the next line you are ok.
userQ.select("cart -_id");

const userCart = await userQ;
```